# mysql timestamp output as formatted Date not working

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have a crazy phenomenon in my php script. I have defined a column as a timestamp in a mysql table. I fill it with the function:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

The data in the table then look like this: 2017-04-19 17:08:45
When I query this column with mysqli as  a unix timestamp again:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP (timestamp) as timestampUnix FROM posts
```

Then binding the result using bind_result to the variable $timestampUnix.

I can echo the variable with

`echo $timestampUnix;`

and it outputs a correct timestamp like this: 1492614559
 however if i do the following:

```
$timestampUnix2 = $timestampUnix;
echo $timestampUnix2;
```

there is simply no echo output... What is the reason?
I tried this because I actually want echo only the date in an other format with:

```
date('d.m.Y', $timestampUnix)
```

and it gave me 01.01.1970  and i wondered why the timestamp must be 0 but it isnt since when i directly echo it it gives me a correct one.

however when i do

```
Date('d.m.Y', 1492614559)
```

it gives me the correct date.. no clue what is going on there!
i know there are many other questions about mysql php Date output, but no one have this issue as i think i cannot do something with the variable i got from the query.

thanks in advance!

edit: i attach the complete code in question:

```
    ---the query that inputs the data in the db----

    $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO posts (timestamp)
            VALUES ('$timestamp')");

    ---the query that fetches the data----

    $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) as timestampUnix FROM posts");


    $results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
    $results->bind_result($timestampUnix); //bind variables to prepared statement

$postdate = date('d.m.Y',$timestampUnix)
echo $postdate;
```

Comment: Could you possibly post an example of your code?

Comment: Yep, show what you really have run in php! Your `echo`s examples work in normal code (Test: `$a=1; echo $a; $b = $a; echo $b;` shows `11`). So show what really is going on.

Comment: Don't use `echo` to print stuff, use `var_dump()`.

Comment: ive attached the complete code in question

Comment: You told: The data in the table then look like this: 2017-04-19 17:08:45, now is it a timestamp or a datetime type column? Are you sure is it timestamp?

Comment: Make sure you assigned to the correct variable names, otherwise $a =$b should give you the value of $b...

Comment: solved it.. i should put the date conversion in a loop since i have multiple output haha, sometimes the devil is in the detail: `[while($results->fetch()){ $postdate =date('d.m.Y',$timestampUnix)
echo $postdate; }`

Comment: @Peter btw its a "timestamp" type colum, and the data inside looks like this:  2017-04-19 17:08:45 but when you do `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(columname)` its outputted as a unix timestamp like: 1492614559. its realy fancy because you have the benefits of human readable data and sorting, and on other hand you can just convert it with this query to a unix timestamp to interact with it in php date() function directly :)